# JQuery how to click html element to copy into text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to click text in a list to add into a text box. I have made a JSON api that gets a list of people in the database. I then have a form that has a text field and displays the list of people. I would like to click a particular person and add it to the text box.

main.js

```
    var ajax_call = function() {
      var $people = $('#people');

      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: '/all/api',
          success: function(people) {
            $.each(people, function(i, person) {
                $people.empty()
            });
            $.each(people, function(i, person) {
              $people.append('<li>name: ' + person.first_name+', last: '+ person.last_name + '</li>');
            });
          }
        });
      $("#people").on("click", "li", function() {
          var content = $(this).html();
         //$("#testbox").val(content);  //replace existing name in textbox
        $("#testbox").val($("#testbox").val() + content + "\n");  //add new name to textbox
});

    };
    var interval = 800;
    setInterval(ajax_call, interval);
```

form.html

```
<form id="textbox" action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="create" />
        </form>

    <ul id="people"></ul>
```

Comment: key up function for  ul? really?

Comment: As Anoop stated, you have a typo (probably a typo) in your code.. Just replace $("#people").keyup with $("#people").click( 
and you should be ok.

Comment: Yea the keyup was a typo. Looking at some of the suggestions now

Comment: I have edited the question from what people have suggested but nothing happens when I click on a person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this "click" function attached to the ul but filtered by the li's (this allows the list to remain dynamic), it allows you to add the individual names (two versions one that overwrites the existing textfield info and the second that appends to it): **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deovgtje/1/)**

```
$("#people").on("click", "li", function() {
    var content = $(this).html();
    //$("#testbox").val(content);  //replace existing name in textbox
    $("#testbox").val($("#testbox").val() + content + "\n");  //add new name to textbox
});
```

Comment: Your demo seems to show exacly what im looking for but when i try and implement it, nothing happens when i click the li. I have updated the code with your example

Comment: Did you also add a textbox or a valid reference to the textbox you want to fill with the clicked names?

Comment: Another typo :( your example worked perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question is pretty easy.
In your code you have the line

```
$("#people").keyup(function() {
```

Which is probably not what you wanted to do, cause now you are waiting for a keyup (release of a key) event on a list. First of all your question stated that you want the user to click and not to press a button and second you want the list items not the list itself.

So IMO you have to change that part to something like:

```
$("li","#people").click(function(){
  var content = this.html();
  $("#testbox").val(content);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

replace this

```
$("#people").keyup(function() {
        var content = $('#people').html();
        $("#testbox").val(content);
    });
```

with this

```
$("#people").click(function() {
        var content = $('#people').html();
        $("#testbox").val(content);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question right away then

```
$("#people").click(function(){
    var content = $('#people').html();
    $("#testbox").val(content);
});
```

should do the work. But I think you should use something like custom attribute instead of id as there can be only one id for a specific tag.